# Unable to open office documents using third party application

Tags: android

I have downloaded some Office files(doc, xls, pdf etc) on SDcard from FTP server and now I want to view those files using third party application.

I am using below code for Intent (in this case a PDF File):

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");


        List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);


        if (list.size() > 0) 
        {
            Uri uri_path = Uri.parse(path);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri_path, "application/pdf");
            try
            {
                startActivity(intent);
            } 
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Application Available to View PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

But when I try to open the file a White Screen appears and disappears. And in DDMS I get the following:

```
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at s.a(Unknown Source)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at com.qo.android.quickcommon.OfficeActivity.a(Unknown Source)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at com.qo.android.quickcommon.OfficeActivity.a(Unknown Source)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at com.qo.android.quickword.Quickword.onCreate(Unknown Source)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1715)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1767)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1005)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
01-14 16:14:17.900: ERROR/Quickoffice(1204):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me on this issue. I don't understand the problem. When I goto SDCard using "ES File Explorer" and opens the file, it gets opened. All the files(doc xls and PDF) gets opened correctly.

Comment: Please dont post stacktraces of obfuscated code. It wont help debugging as in this case it is showing error at at com.qo.android.quickcommon.OfficeActivity.a(Unknown Source) . Atleast properly configure the proguard file to display filename and line number by including "keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer. I needed to add the following for my URI:

```
File file = new File(path);
Uri uri_path = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent.setDataAndType(uri_path, "application/pdf");
try
{
    startActivity(intent);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Application Available to View PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```